# Why is my weight paint inverted?

Tags: objects

So I am following Blender Guru's donut tutorial. I want the sprinkles to be on top. I painted only on the top but then it's where the sprinkles are not so I painted on the sides. Is this how it's supposed to work? and also how do I keep the sprinkles on top of the donut. There is one rogue sprinkle in the second image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, that is not how it supposed to work. I’m not sure how you did this. The rogue sprinkle is probably because some vertex over there as a weight that allows sprinkles, but the subdivision surface modifier moves it, so the sprinkle appears on the side of the donut. Try putting the sprinkle modifier after the subdivision surface modifier.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm a complete beginner. Where do I do that?

Comment: In the modifiers tab of the properties editor. Didn’t you put a subdivision surface modifier on the icing? Well, anyway, right now you’re in the particles settings tab of the properties editor, and the modifiers tab is right above it. The blue wrench.

Comment: I did put a subdivision surface modifier but I clicked apply on it and it's long gone. I only have the particle settings on the modifier tab.

Comment: OK. Well, I really don’t know what’s causing this, especially the fact that the vertices are appearing on the area with zero weight instead of the other way around. Can you provide your blend file?

Comment: in the Particles panel > Vertex Groups > Density, have you clicked on the <-> button?

Comment: Here is my blend file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/10IDYFcEFq329Dd_tI23xNhrUIyBROh-0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

You've inverted the vertex group density effect with the <-> button:

[image]

Comment: This fixed the problem! thank you so much!

Comment: Now how do I get rid of the rogue sprinkles?

Comment: you have also painted underneath so you need to correct the weight paint underneath as well

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: you need to weight paint the same way, to subtract weight, once in Weight Paint mode, in the N panel > Tool > Brush Settings > Blend > Choose Subtract, and on the top header menu of the 3D view window, make sure your Weight value is at 1

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your answer!